# Array isn't getting set in switch statement in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set an array in a class from another activity in Android.

here is my main activity:

```
public class main_activity extends Activity {
  int i = 0;
  TextView title;
  TextView inst;
  TextView word;
  EditText edittext;
  Button btn;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_four);

   MyArray mine = new MyArray();
   mine.shuffle(getApplicationContext());
  }
}
```

Here is myArray:

```
public class MyArray{
  String[] words = new String[2];

  public void choose(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
      words[0] = "zero";
      words[1] = "one";
      break;
    case 2:
      words[0] = "two";
      words[1] = "three";
  }

  public void shuffle(Context mcontext) {
    MyArray mine = new MyArray();
     mine.choose(2);
     Log.d("TEST", words[1]);
     Log.d("TEST", words[2]);
  }
}
```

I get a force close with a NullPointer error on `Log.d("TEST", words[1]);`. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code for chooseList? The code for MyArray only gives a choose method, not a chooseList.

Comment: Sorry updated it. I was shortening my code a bit so that the method names are easier to read.

Comment: Not a null pointer, but you'll get an out-of-bounds on the next line (`words[2]`)

Comment: Please post code that is an exact copy-paste of code you have run and that definitely reproduces the problem.

Comment: MyArray is a class. The code is an exact copy and paste expect for the method names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `shuffle()` method to this:

```
public void shuffle() {
    choose(2);
    Log.d("TEST", words[0]);
    Log.d("TEST", words[1]);
}
```

This will take care of the null pointer, since you're not creating a local `mine`, which you don't need.

It will also fix the out of bounds you'll get next, since you're trying to access array member `2`, which doesn't exist.

It also eliminates the `Context` you're passing, apparently for no reason.

Comment: Yep. Ah. So simple. Thanks for explaining everything also. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Your `words` array is getting initialized, but only in the `mine` object, not in the `shuffle` method's own `this` object.  It's unclear why you are creating a separate `MyArray` object in your `shuffle` method, calling *its* `choose` method, then attempting to access your own `words` array.

Edited to match question edit to change `myArray` to `MyArray`.

Comment: So, I should just do write `choose(2)` in the shuffle method instead of creating a new object?

Comment: Yes; it looks like you want to initialize the members of your own array instead of the array of some other `MyArray` object.

Answer (score 0):

you know that the onCreate MyArray has a capital 'm' and the name of the class the 'm' is lowercase and in the log it says position 2 theres only 0 and 1